# Kendo Treeview / jQuery: Looping through children of children in unordered list

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm trying to get the innerText of all the children in the selected node.

So if user clicks on one of the ULs I would like to get the text of that UL and any children (ULs and/or LIs) and write it to the console.

```
$("#removeNode").click(function (e) {
    var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    var selectedNode = treeview.select();

    console.log(selectedNode.text());
});
```

The above console.log give me "LLC-A Alpine LLC-B Seminole LLC-C Commons Chase" as an example but I need to list each individually as:

LLC-A

Alpine

LLC-B

Seminole

LLC-C

Commons

Chase

Sample Unorded List:

```
<ul class="k-group" style="border-style: none;">
<li class="k-item k-first k-last" data-id="BASE" id="BASE" data-uid="31f1f67d-89f9-40e7-b646-29a9597056c7">
    <div class="k-top k-bot"><span class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in" data-expanded="true">Test</span></div>
    <ul class="k-group" style="border-style: none;">
        <li class="k-item k-last" data-uid="aec27c8c-ca89-49e8-bfd3-0cede391a55e">
            <div class="k-bot"><span class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in" data-expanded="true">LLC-A</span></div>
            <ul class="k-group" style="border-style: none;">
                <li class="k-item" data-uid="78810005-52ad-42ae-92dd-7245b6960eb6">
                    <div class="k-top"><span class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in" data-expanded="true">LLC-B</span></div>
                    <ul class="k-group" style="border-style: none;">
                        <li class="k-item" data-uid="bd9866fb-c997-41ae-a4c2-d5576f391a9c">
                            <div class="k-top"><span class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in" data-expanded="true">LLC-C</span></div>
                            <ul class="k-group" style="border-style: none;">
                                <li class="k-item" data-uid="31c48db8-c9d2-4f40-b2ba-f42197811e56">
                                    <div class="k-top"><span class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in" data-expanded="true">LLC-D</span></div>
                                    <ul class="k-group" style="border-style: none;">
                                        <li class="k-item k-last" data-uid="778c3538-7fbc-4daf-8b7d-b6f3cca5b6fd">
                                            <div class="k-bot"><span class="k-in">Beacon</span></div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="k-item k-last" data-uid="f9e673c0-902c-4ede-b5c4-ccd2232391a4">
                                    <div class="k-bot"><span class="k-in">Willows</span></div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="k-item" data-uid="c0f42f30-cb84-4f66-a37e-e96a0b0cfcbf">
                            <div class="k-mid"><span class="k-in">Chase</span></div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="k-item k-last" data-uid="7b7053bd-38ee-4312-9e78-484b4da48e0d">
                            <div class="k-bot"><span class="k-icon k-minus"></span><span class="k-in" data-expanded="true">LLC-F</span></div>
                            <ul class="k-group" style="border-style: none;">
                                <li class="k-item" data-uid="c0dad4b9-1839-4dca-ac1f-2fe9fc2df5ed">
                                    <div class="k-top"><span class="k-in">Seminole</span></div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="k-item k-last" data-uid="8c4073be-4b8c-4036-a85c-efe36bda1466">
                                    <div class="k-bot"><span class="k-in">Commons</span></div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="k-item k-last" data-uid="39644343-4b0c-4be0-be08-701f63096195">
                    <div class="k-bot"><span class="k-in">Alpine</span></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: It's hard to follow exactly what you're trying to do. (I don't see kendoTreeView anywhere in the markup, for starters.) Past that, I don't see any discernible similarities between the nodes that you say should be printed for your node. They're not all children of the same element; nor are they the same element class or even with the same HTML5 data attributes. Please clarify the markup and elaborate about the goal…

Comment: I'll give an example of what I'm trying to do.

If I click the text "LLC-F" I want to list each item under it in the console. With my current click function I get all the names on one line when I output it to the console.

Comment: In my click function, when I do the console.log this is what I'm getting in the console: innerText: "LLC-A↵LLC-B↵LLC-C↵Seminole↵Beacon↵Alpine↵"

How can I loop through an get each individual name?

Comment: By what criteria are you finding these nodes? It looks like you're just fetching the text of the node, which just gives you a string. Seems like a better approach would be to have some sort of structure you could rely on. For instance, what's the relationship between LLC-C and Commons, which appears related to LLC-F AFAICT. Chase is in another DOM path altogether as well. If you have criteria and structure, you can use jQuery's selectors to find them all. Otherwise you'll be looking at fragile regex split string processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text jQuery function will return the inner text of a DOM node and all its children. In this particular case you can just split the text and then join it back. Here is what I mean:

http://jsbin.com/edahit/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing and it appears to be working....so far.

```
           var lis = $(".k-in", selectedNode);

            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
                var name = lis[i].innerText;
                console.log(name);
            }
```